# Setting Google Maps Height to Image Height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

On each page, I have a banner at the top. The banners are 1980px by 657px.

HTML:

```
    <div class="services banner">
        <img src="images/services/banner.jpg">
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .banner {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .banner img {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        display: block;
    }
```

So the height is dependent on the image and viewport size.

On my contact page, I want to have a Google Map instead of a banner. My issue is that I want it to be the same height as the banners. I was hoping I could just put a transparent banner inside of the #map div, but any classes or contents added to #map div disappear.

Any ideas how to achieve this with CSS or JS?

**Using Empi's answer, I came up with the following solution:**

HTML:

```
    <div class="contact banner">
        <img id="dummy" src="images/contact/banner.jpg" style="display: none;">
    </div>
    <div id="googlemap">
        <div id="map"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    #googlemap {
        width: 100%;
    }

    #map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: #001f37;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

JS:

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var imgHeight = $('#dummy').height();
    $('#googlemap').height(imgHeight);
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    var imgHeight = $('#dummy').height();
    $('#googlemap').height(imgHeight);
});
```

It's a bit hacky, but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Empi/7n8mT/)?

Get width / height in jQuery. Apply it to the maps. Display: none on the image. A bit a dirty answer but it does the trick. I don't know how you would do it in pure css.

### HTML

```html
<div id="con">
<img id="img" src="http://dummyimage.com/600x200/000/fff.jpg" />
<iframe id="maps" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d76608.9275331472!2d23.1560658!3d53.127625249999994!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x471ffc048f41971d%3A0x72317dcc8bf07b2c!2sBia%C5%82ystok!5e0!3m2!1snl!2spl!4v1397752663976"></iframe>
</div>
```

### CSS

```css
#con {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  background-color: gray;
}

#img {
  display: none;
}

#maps {    
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  border: none;
}
```

### jQuery

```js
var imgWidth = $('#img').width();
var imgHeight = $('#img').height();

$('#maps').width(imgWidth);
$('#maps').height(imgHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you not just set the height of the `#map` div to `auto`, just as you do with your banner?

Is there some reason you could not do this?

Comment: If you just set height to auto, the map will not display. Right now I have: #map { width: 100%; background: #001f37; margin: 0 auto; height: 60%; }

Comment: Ok sorry, so your banner gets set to the height of the image inside it, right? I think you could either find out what the height of your image is (150px?) and manually set the height of the #map div to the same value. Alternatively, if your image changes dimensions frequently (no idea why that would be), you could consider loading it behind your map div (using z-index) and scaling the map div to 100%. I think that would be an ugly way to go about it though.

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly certain that when you use tell Google Maps which div to append to, it removes all content from that div. In this case that probably includes your image.

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned that in my post. I'm just trying to find a way to keep the same dimensions as the banners if possible.