# how to Change image height and width in google maps icon

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, laravel-5

In this code i m displaying the multi-pointers in my google map but the image dosnt work properly

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       var locations = <?php print_r(json_encode($deliverer)) ?>;
       var mymap = new GMaps({
         el: '#mymap',
         lat: 30.375321,
         lng: 69.345116,
         zoom:6
       });


       $.each( locations, function( index, value ){
            mymap.addMarker({
              lat: value.latitude,
              lng: value.longitude,


>  **icon: "car_marker.png";**


    icon: "car_marker.png";   ,,,,this is my image i just want to display in google map ,so how can i change the height and width in it ???
            });
      });
     </script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting Google Maps Height to Image Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23137663/setting-google-maps-height-to-image-height)

Comment: <?php print_r(json_encode($deliverer)) ?>;

"$deliverver" is my Database ,Latitude and longitude is stored in it

and

addMarker funtion shows the multiple pointer on map according to their lat and lng

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this, make and object of map marker icon, with their configurations,

```
      var ico = '<?php echo asset("assets/images/map_marker.png"); ?>';
        var image = {
          url: ico,
          size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
          origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
          scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50)
        };
```

Its make an marker icon of size passed into it you can change as per your need and see what happen.

Then you can pass this to marker like this,

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: {lat: location.lat + (Math.random() -.5) / 1500, lng: location.lon + (Math.random() -.5) / 1500 },
            title: location.title,
            icon:image,
        });
```

Thank you.
I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank u soo much ,,it really helpful :)

Comment: Wel-come brother if it helps you to solve your issue do not forget to mark it as right with up vote